# Bash script to insert log into BigQuery table

Tags: mysql, bash, google-bigquery, matillion

I am using Matillion as my etl tool and I am trying to expose the log files for packages/ jobs and dump those into a BigQuery table.  I was hoping to use the Bash Script Component to help me accomplish this.

So implementing my own log in the job with something like the following

```
echo “$(date) Starting” >> /tmp/logfile.log
```

I wanted to insert this into my table ${tablename}

Thanks

Comment: Can you use `bq insert`? See the [command line reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_insert). Note that streaming has a cost of $0.01 per 200 MB of inserts.

Answer (score 0):

You could copy/move the tmp file to GCS in your Bash Script and use GCS Load at the end of the job.

Answer (score 0):

I think BigQuery component in Matillion might be able to help you. 
there is some configuration involved though before you can have a handshake between Matillion and GCP ( I am assuming you are using Matillion for snowflake or Redshift ) [Here is the configuration part](https://snowflake-support.matillion.com/s/article/6717597)